# How to edit the filters e-mail with a Thunderbird extension?

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am creating an extension that will perform some actions to filter certain messages.

I thought about creating my own email filter that would check every message that arrives, but Thunderbird already has it, so the extension could become unstable.

I want to know how I can **create, edit and modify** the Thunderbird email filters through an extension (with Javascript).